# diagonal scroll animation of uiimageview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, scroll, coverflow

What I want to do is detect the diagonal scroll of user and move the views into the direction of the scroll. I want to achieve a coverflow-style animation except the arrangement of my views are somewhat circular.

---EDIT---

I have used iCarousel to try and implement this, so far it has been successfully done by using the iCarouselTypeCustom type in vertical position and override the carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform: method with:

```
CGFloat theFloat = 0;
if (offset > 0) {
    theFloat = offset * 30;
}
else {
    theFloat = offset * -30;
}
return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, theFloat, offset * 40, 0);
```

the current problem is that when i scroll down the arrangement of views are not correct. The view on the lower part of the screen should be on the top of the other view. I have attached a screenshot for this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest this [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) by NickLockwood. Great Project. You can tweak it the way you want it, believe me. Make it vertical, and look up into its type cause it supports 11 types including the coverflow you want. Check it out!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @superman. I have tried this code but I can't seem to get the vertical swipe, even when I remove the "//ignore vertical swipes" part of the code.

Comment: dont remove codes. probably just disable that. and make it vertical. swiping is embedded in the code.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently utilizing the iCarouselTypeTimeMachine type in vertical position. I will be editing my question to update with current status.

Comment: how about the inverted time machine? I guess that should work.